# Using Google Tag(gtag) with Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, gtag.js

I currently have an implementation of GA4 using gtag in my website and I would like to add GTM too. I was wondering if I can use the same endpoint from GA4 (`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=`) and insert the GTM tag where id is and GA4 and GTM again with `config`.

I found this for the documentation
`<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=TAG_ID"></script>` but nothing that specifically talks about using Google Tag with Google Tag Manager. Almost all of it is about using the GTM interface.

I found that GTM supports googletag but the endpoint uses `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?`

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended since GTM can load gtag and a bunch of other libraries as they're needed and manage them in the most optimal way. That's why you see a lot more information on GTM than gtag.

Implementing tracking with gtag.js is, in most cases, a mistake unless you don't care much about it and just want to be quick about it.

Having said that, yes, you can load both separately. GTM will attempt to use the existing gtag library if it needs it. Set up like this, however, requires you to understand how both libraries deploy listeners to the dataLayer array and how they store/use the local state of things. They will also use the same cookies.

Even though the libraries don't conflict in terms of syntax, it's uncommon to have logical tracking issues due to implementations like this.